# YouTube Data API v3 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I'm getting this error in my code, when working with the YouTube API. This code worked previously and nothing has changed about my code.
I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
https://content-youtube.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.myOGgYJo9ys.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCMR2Cg_3Iqxcgmos-E9G6cjWQG_Kw%2Fm%3D__features__#parent=https%3A%2F%2Fcreatorinventory.com&rpctoken=657579414
```

I get this error after successfully signing in with oauth2 and calling the api. This is some of my code:

```
function handleClientLoad(){
  gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
}

function initClient(){
    gapi.client.init({
        discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
        clientId: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(() => {
        // Listen for sign state changes
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
        // Handle initial sign in state
        updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
        authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
        signoutButton.onclick = handleSignouClick;
    });
}

function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn)
{
    if(isSignedIn){
        //Update UI
        signinCont.style.display = 'none';
        signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
        loading.style.display = 'block';
        //get Channel
        gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
          "part": [
            "snippet,contentDetails,statistics"
          ],
          "mine": true
        })
        .then(async function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            channel_id = response.result.items[0]['id'];
        }
        function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
}

function handleAuthClick(){
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
}
```

My code has worked previously, but now isn't. I don't believe I've changed anything. Could it be an issue on Google/YouTube's end?

Comment: Yes the issue is completely on their side currently i'm facing the same issue here